# How to get the file name in server temp folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the temp file in my Temp folder in the server. I have tried this

```
@"\\"Server.MachineName + @"\Temp"
```

but it's not working properly. I don't want to use

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()
```

Please advise.

Comment: Define "it's not working properly."

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen When i save my file in that location I'm not able later to read it even though I have the right permissions

Comment: You have an APP_DATA folder from the root of your site where you can read/write your data, temporary or not.

Comment: @Steve yes i do have APP_DATA folder but no data exists there to read and write